# 7zip - self-extracting executables require admin privileges and trigger compatibility warning

Tags: windows-7, uac, 7-zip, self-extracting

When I create self-extracting archive executables for Windows with 7zip, the .EXEs trigger UAC on Windows7. And frequently after unzipping, I get this:

[image]

I'm using commandline like: `7z a -sfx7z.sfx dir\`. Why are these things happening and can I fix them?

Answer (score 3):

You may want to disable this warning, if so, follow the steps below.

1. Open Service Manager(press [image] `+` <kbd>R</kbd>, type `services.msc` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>).
2. Search for `Program Compatibility Assistance Service` in the list.
3. Right click on this service and select **`Stop`**.
4. Now again right click on `Program Compatibility Assistance Service` and select `Properties`.
5. Under `General` tab in the `Startup type` section, click on the drop-down menu and select **`Disabled`**.
6. Click on `Apply` then `OK`.

*Note: Program Compatibility Assistance monitors programs for known compatibility issues and can be very beneficial for end users. This tip is aimed at power users.*

---

Another [`probable solution`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371711.aspx) is to embed a manifest file to avoid this alert. Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> 
  <assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0"> 
    <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1"> 
      <application> 
        <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows 7 --> 
          <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/> 
      </application> 
    </compatibility>
  </assembly>
```

How to embed the [`application manifest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371711.aspx) into my executable?

You can use this utility([`mt.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375649%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - assuming you have the sdk installed) from Microsoft to do this. You would use a similar command like this:

```
mt.exe  -manifest "foo.manifest" -outputresource:"foo.exe";#1
```

---

### Other Considerations

- Consider using this program([`7z SFX-Creator`](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Compression-tools/7z-SFX-Creator.shtml)), according to this page: *self-extracting archives created will no longer cause alert PCA*.
- See if [IExpress](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb496369.aspx) may be useful to you
  [image]

Comment: Disabling the warning doesn't help, the end users cannot be expected to modify their computer setup. I've never seen this when _receiving_ self-extracting archives, is it a bug in 7zip? Also - any idea why it needs admin rights? The folder in question isn't a protected one like Program Files.

Comment: IExpress is a great free (and semi-secret) feature in Windows but sadly doesn't support directories only a flat file structure.

Answer (score 3):

Your self-extracting archive likely contains `setup` or `install` in its file name. In this case, Windows expects it installs an application.

If Windows does not detect “usual installer activity”, it assumes the installation failed because of missing administrator privileges. That's the reason why it prompts to re-run installation *using recommended settings*, with elevated privileges.

This heuristic is used where the executable does not have [`requestedExecutionLevel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) element in its manifest.

This issues could have been fixed in a newer version of 7zip self-extracting module.